# jquery delay image animate

Tags: jquery, delay

I am from Argentina and I have a question I hope you can help me.

I am creating a slider and I have a problem with the following code.

```
var tmpImg = new Image() ;
tmpImg.src ='http://mlm-s1-p.mlstatic.com/reloj-movado-movimien-de-cuarzo-con-caja-dorada-y-tapa-acero-4269-MLM4903532600_082013-F.jpg';


tmpImg.onload = function() {

var alto =tmpImg.height;
var largo =tmpImg.width;

$("#foto").animate({

width: largo,
height:alto,

},

{
    duration: 500,

 step: function(){     

$('#foto').css({
               position:'absolute',
               left: ($(window).width() - $('#foto').outerWidth())/2,
               top: ($(window).height() - $('#foto').outerHeight())/2
          });
    }
});

$("#foto").append(tmpImg);

    } ;
```

the only thing that interests me about all this is that the foto is loaded when the animation is finished.

```
$("#foto").append(tmpImg);
```

sorry for the English and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to preload your photo before showing. Example with JQuery:

```
$(new Image()).attr('src', '/img/preload_me_plz.jpg').load(function() {
            alert('i am ready!');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `complete` option to do so:

```
$("#foto").animate({

width: largo,
height:alto,

},

{
    duration: 500,

 step: function(){     

$('#foto').css({
               position:'absolute',
               left: ($(window).width() - $('#foto').outerWidth())/2,
               top: ($(window).height() - $('#foto').outerHeight())/2
          });
    },

  complete: function (){
     $("#foto").append(tmpImg);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am a bit confused what you really want to see

Answer (score 0):

Here I have given example code to execute function after animation complete. May be useful

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
      $( "#book" ).animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=50",
        height: "toggle"
      }, 5000, function() {
        // Here animation complete. You can write your code here.
      });
    });
```